# How to convey this formula in Excel?

Tags: excel, excel-formula, pseudocode

I've been trying to write an excel formula but have been having no luck in making it work. I can easily write the formula in pseudo code, but cannot convert it to excel!

```
IF (ISERROR(A) OR A == 0) {
    IF (ISERROR(B) OR B == 0) {
        return 2958465;
    } ELSE {
        return B;
    }
} ELSE {
    return A;
}
```

This is what I've got so far, but it doesn't work when I change A and B to their VLOOKUP formulas like I want to:

`=IF(OR(ISERROR(A), A = 0),IF(OR(ISERROR(B), B = 0),2958465,B),A)`

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it with this formula:

`=IF(IFERROR(VLOOKUP([@[Serial '#]], Table4, 184, FALSE), IFERROR(VLOOKUP([@AssetTag], Table48, 184, FALSE), 2958465)) = 0, 2958465, IFERROR(VLOOKUP([@[Serial '#]], Table4, 184, FALSE), IFERROR(VLOOKUP([@AssetTag], Table48, 184, FALSE), 2958465)))`

It doesn't feel very elegant, but it works!

Comment: Less repetition with this setup: `=IF(IFERROR(A,0)=0,IF(IFERROR(B,0)=0,2958465,B),A)`